# NestJS JWT Strategy requires a secret or key

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js, nestjs

In my NestJS Node application, I have set up JWT authentication using Passport (as per https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication) however I am attempting to keep the JWT Key in environment files which are retrieved using the built-in ConfigService.

```js
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('JWT_KEY'),
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' }
    });
  }
```

The module is registered as follows:

```js
JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_KEY')
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService]
    })
```

I am getting the following error when starting the app:

```
api: [Nest] 16244   - 03/27/2020, 10:52:00   [ExceptionHandler] JwtStrategy requires a secret or key +1ms
```

It appears that the JWTStrategy class is instantiating before the ConfigService is ready to provide the JWT Key and is returning undefined within the Strategy when calling `configService.get<string>('JWT_KEY')`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I ensure that the ConfigService is ready prior to attempting to retrieve any environment variables?

UPDATE:
Entire AuthModule is below:

```js
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './strategies/jwt.strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

const passportModule = PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' });
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    passportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_KEY')
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService]
    })
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService, AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [passportModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Can you also add your `PassportModule`'s registration?

Comment: My PassportModule is registered:
```const passportModule = PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' });``` and is then added to my imports array.

Comment: Can you show your entire `AuthModule` then? I can't see anything inherently wrong, and I've got a set up where I pass my `ConfigService` to a `Strategy` class working

Comment: Sure, added entire AuthModule to the original question for clarity.

Comment: I encountered the same error even if I'm getting the key from .env also tried hardcoding the key but the same error occurred.

Comment: @jongbanaag what was you solution?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm going to be willing to bet that the issue is that you are not `import`ing the `ConfigModule` to the `AuthModule` and instead you are adding the `ConfigService` to the `providers` array directly. This would mean that if `ConfigModule` does any sort of set up on the `ConfigService`, it won't be happening anymore. What you should have instead is something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    UserModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_KEY')
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  providers: [LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy, AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [PassportStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Now as long a `ConfigModule` `exports` `ConfigService`, the `AuthModule` should fire up just fine.

Comment: It appears that the issue is not with the key being pulled into the AuthModule, but with it being pulled into the JWTStrategy itself. I have followed the above and many thanks for your assistance. But when the JWTStrategy is being instantiated, which appears to happen before the AuthModule?!, the configService is returning undefined for this value.

Comment: Do you have the `JwtStrategy` being added anywhere else? Like I said, I have a setup where a strategy has the `ConfigService` injected and it's working as expected

Comment: I have just realised there was a typo in the JWTStrategy. I had put JWT_KET instead of JWT_KEY... Thanks everyone for their help. D'oh. *facepalm*

Comment: literally toke me 4hrs to get to your answer. Thanks a lot. Take care.

Comment: How can I get TOKEN value from an ASYNC config service in JwtStrategy's super call?

`super({token: await authConfig.getConfig.jwtToken})`

I am using AWS Secret Manager for storing sensitive values.

Comment: If it's in a `super()` call, you can't. You would need to use an async `factory` to make the async call, and then inject the result.

Answer (score 0):

If [@Jay McDoniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889465/15460607) answer doesn't work, please ensure the env file existence and correct the env key ("JWT_KEY")

Answer (score -7):

if you've tried all above options then just delete your dist folder then try again it would work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).